# How to Get the Direct Access Index for NSDictionary of NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, multidimensional-array, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here's the code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *circuit_step = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];    
NSMutableDictionary *step_info    = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

 [step_info setObject: @"search"   forKey: @"search-type"];     
 [step_info setObject: @"small"   forKey: @"search-format"];     
 [step_info setObject: @"winter"   forKey: @"search-season"];    
 [step_info setObject: @"tree"   forKey: @"search-location"];

 **[circuit_step setObject: circuit_step forKey: @"01"];**

 [step_info setObject: @"search"   forKey: @"search-type"]; 
 [step_info setObject: @"micro"   forKey: @"search-format"];     
 [step_info setObject: @"summer"   forKey: @"search-season"];    
 [step_info setObject: @"by the lake"          forKey: @"search-location"];

 **[circuit_step setObject: circuit_step forKey: @"02"];**
```

What is the code to do a direct access on `dictionary circuit_step key "01"` and `dictionary step_info key "search-location"` in a format suitable for NSLog?

Comment: There are no arrays in your code.

Comment: Hi St3fan, I did add the arrays statement at the top

Comment: Still they're not arrays but dictionaries. and what is NSLog format?

Comment: Sorry ST3fan, I mean dictionaries, NSLog is just to echo it to the console, I just need to read directly circuit_step '01' step_info 'search-location'

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
NSLog(@"Value is %@",
    [[circuit_step objectForKey: @"01"] objectForKey: @"search-location"])
```

Also, your code is all wrong. Here is a fixed version:

```
NSMutableDictionary *circuit_step = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
if (circuit_step != nil)
{
    NSMutableDictionary* step_info = nil;

    step_info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if (step_info != nil) {
        [step_info setObject: @"search" forKey: @"search-type"];
        [step_info setObject: @"small" forKey: @"search-format"];
        [step_info setObject: @"winter" forKey: @"search-season"];
        [step_info setObject: @"tree" forKey: @"search-location"];
        [circuit_step setObject: step_info forKey: @"01"];
    }

    step_info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if (step_info != nil) {     
        [step_info setObject: @"search" forKey: @"search-type"];
        [step_info setObject: @"micro" forKey: @"search-format"];
        [step_info setObject: @"summer" forKey: @"search-season"];
        [step_info setObject: @"by the lake" forKey: @"search-location"];
        [circuit_step setObject: step_info forKey: @"02"];
    }
}
```

You were not setting the right object in circuit_step and you were also reusing a dictionary so you would end up with two entries pointing to the same dictionary with the values of '02'.

Comment: St3fan, for my understanding, what is the difference between those 3 lines:

1- NSMutableDictionary* step_info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


2- NSMutableDictionary* step_info = nil;


3- step_info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

Thank's

Comment: Minor quibble. The preferred initializers for all mutable collects are  the variants of `initWithCapacity`. In this case, you would want to use either 'dictionaryWithCapcity;' or ``initWithCapacity:`. Simple set the capacity to 1 to start. Using an inherited generic initializer can sometimes lead to odd problems.

Comment: If I don't put the line "step_info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];" between the 2 if statement paragraph, I loose values in step_info of circuit_step for key "01", but it is already saved. 

Why that line is required ?

Comment: @TechZen what kind of odd problems? I have *never* encountered any odd problems by not using those alternative initializers. Also, they are not preferred. Simply an alternative.

Comment: @gpsdev you need two dictionaries because nothing is copied. The parent dictionary simply *references* the two other dictionaries. So if you do not create two new instances then both 01 and 02 will point to the same single instance.

Comment: Ok I got the idea, in PHP that would have worked, but now I need to get used of the memory pointing mechanism with objective-c.

Thank's for your help again St3fan !

Comment: @St3fan -- usually failure to respond to selectors and memory issues. On the other hand, it might be a fossil issue. Class specific initializers where something drilled into me when I was learning NextStep 10 years ago at Apple. Perhaps in Objective-C 2.0 it's no longer an issue

Comment: @TechZen - I'm sure it has been fixed. The documentation specifically states that `dictionary` may be used to create mutable dictionaries.